# Internet connectivity using linux network namespace

Tags: linux, route, namespace, network-namespaces

I experimenting with Linux namespaces on Ubuntu 17.1 distro. Ultimate goal is to force an application to use a particular network interface via a 3G modem not the intranet wired connection. My PC has 3 network interfaces.

*enp0s25:* wired to a intranet router w/o internet connectivity
inet 10.18.0.101

*wlp3s0:* wireless, used for remote management, will not be available in production environment
inet 10.11.1.116

*enx8cae4cff1c86:* wired, simulating a 4G USB mobile modem eventually will be used in production environment
inet 10.11.1.142

wlp3s0 and enx8cae4cff1c86 are connected to the same router.I have used following code to created a name space called *mobilens*

```
ip netns add mobilens
ip link set dev enx8cae4cff1c86 netns mobilens
ip netns exec mobilens ifconfig enx8cae4cff1c86 10.1.1.10/24 up
ip netns exec mobilens ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1/8 up
ip netns exec mobilens route add default gw 10.1.1.1
ip netns exec mobilens dhcpcd enx8cae4cff1c86
```

I have also created a /etc/netns/mobilens/resolv.conf file with following entries

```
nameserver 10.11.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search google.com
```

Running ifconfig in name space with

```
ip netns exec mobilens ifconfig
```

returns
inet 10.1.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0
and if I query DNS servers used in namespace as follows

```
ip netns exec mobilens nmcli dev show | grep DNS
```

it returns

IP4.DNS[1]: 10.11.1.1

I try to ping google.com using this namespace it resolves but fails.

```
ip netns exec mobilens ping www.google.com
```

PING www.google.com (172.217.7.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.1.1.10 (10.1.1.10) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.1.1.10 (10.1.1.10) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

What else I need to do to be able to access to internet via this namespace?

EDIT 1:
Using xterm in the namespace, indeed makes testing easier.
I also started to using

```
dhclient -d enx8cae4cff1c86
```

instead of DHSCP server in namespace. 
However problem continues.I am thinking this is somewhat due to routing. Following is result of route command from interfaces outside of namespace

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlp3s0
10.11.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlp3s0
10.18.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s25
10.18.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25
```

and this one from namespace

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enx8cae4cff1c86
10.11.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enx8cae4cff1c86
10.1.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enx8cae4cff1c86
```

Any suggestions about possible modifications to routing in namespace?

Answer (score 2):

[Solved]
Solution was to modify default gateway. I added following line to namespace configuration file.

```
ip netns exec mobilens ip route change default via 10.11.1.1 dev enx8cae4cff1c86
```

This step was enough for me to ping www.google.com
However when I disabled the management wifi connection, ping gave errors related to name resolution. I solved this problem by creating a file in \etc\netns\mobilens\resolv.conf
File contained:

```
nameserver 10.11.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search google.com
```

Now I can access to internet for any given domain.

Comment: What is the IP address for enx8cae4cff1c86 with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

First, start an xterm in the network namespace, so you have an easier time testing. I prefer mine colored, and with my userid instead of root:

```
ip netns exec mobilens su -c "xterm -bg yellow &" my_userid
```

Second, you are running a DHCP *server* in that namespace, instead of a client, and you are *also* running Network Manager. What you want is a DHCP *client* in that namespace, or a static configuration. And I've no idea what Network Manager will do when confronted with multiple namespaces (I've had bad experience with NM, I can never get it to do what I want).

So: *Either* look at what NM is doing to the interfaces in your namespace (and stop NM if it's getting in the way), *or* configure them statically with the correct gateway, route and namerserver, *or* use a DHCP client, e.g. `dhclient -d enx8cae4cff1c86` and watch the output to see it's properly assigning everything.

In doubt, run `tcpdump` on the interface and see if the packets go out properly.